# update related input text with drag marker or point in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am posting my complete code given below, this is working fine in all cases instead of one thing. I would like for when I drag the points I would like to change the input text address with the changed address.

Complete code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        /* Autocomplete styles */
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

        #map {
            height: 70%;
            width: 80%;
        }


        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .controls {
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 32px;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        #start,
        #waypoints,
        #end {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #start:focus,
        #waypoints:focus,
        #end:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        #mode-selector {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
        }

        #mode-selector label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        #right-panel {
            font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        #right-panel select,
        #right-panel input {
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        #right-panel select {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #right-panel i {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        #right-panel {
            float: right;
            width: 34%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .panel {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Autocomplete html -->
    <input id="start" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter an origin location">

    <input id="end" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a destination location">

    <input id="waypoints1" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a stop">
    <input id="waypoints2" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a stop">

    <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
        <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
        <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
        <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Draggable directions hmtl -->
    <div id="right-panel">
        <p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
        // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
        // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeControl: false,
                center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
                zoom: 13
            });

            new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
        }

        /**
         * @constructor
        */
        function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
            this.map = map;
            this.originPlaceId = null;
            this.destinationPlaceId = null;
            this.destinationPlaceId2 = null;
            this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
            var originInput = document.getElementById('start');
            var destinationInput = document.getElementById('end');
            var destinationInput2 = document.getElementById('waypoints1');
            var destinationInput3 = document.getElementById('waypoints2');
            // var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
            // var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
            var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
            this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
            // added draggable marker option to the renderer and right panel
            this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                draggable: true,
                map: map,
                panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
            });


            var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
            originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

            var destinationAutocomplete2 =
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput2);
            destinationAutocomplete2.setFields(['place_id']);

            var destinationAutocomplete3 =
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput3);
            destinationAutocomplete3.setFields(['place_id']);

            var destinationAutocomplete =
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
            // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
            destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);


            this.directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function () {
                var routes = this.getDirections().routes[0];
                routes_list = []
                for (var i = 0; i < routes.legs.length; i++) {
                    //   alert(routes.legs[i].start_address)
                    //   alert(routes.legs[i].end_address)
                    //   routes_list.push(routes.legs[i].start_address)
                    //   console.log(routes.legs[i])
                    //   alert(routes.legs[i])
                    //   var routeSegment = i + 1;
                    //   summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
                    //     '</b><br>';
                    //   summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                    //   summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                    //   summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                }
                computeTotalDistance(this.getDirections());
            });
            this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
            this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
            this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

            this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
            this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
            this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete2, 'DEST2');
            this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete3, 'DEST3');

            this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
            this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
            this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput2);
            this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput3);
            this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
        }

        // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
        // Autocomplete.
        AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function (id, mode) {
            var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
            var me = this;
            radioButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                me.travelMode = mode;
                me.route();
            });
        };

        AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function (autocomplete, mode) {
            var me = this;
            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (!place.place_id) {
                    window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
                    return;
                }
                if (mode === 'ORIG') {
                    me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
                } else if (mode === 'DEST') {
                    me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
                } else if (mode === 'DEST2') {
                    me.destinationPlaceId2 = place.place_id;
                } else if (mode === 'DEST3') {
                    me.destinationPlaceId3 = place.place_id;
                }
                me.route();
            });

        };

        AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function () {
            console.log("originPlaceId=" + this.originPlaceId + " destinationPlaceId=" + this.destinationPlaceId + " destinationPlaceId2=" + this.destinationPlaceId2 + " destinationPlaceId3=" + this.destinationPlaceId3)
            if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
                return;
            }

            var me = this;

            var waypts = [];
            if (!!this.destinationPlaceId2) {
                waypts.push({
                    location: {
                        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId2
                    },
                    stopover: true
                });
            }

            if (!!this.destinationPlaceId3) {
                waypts.push({
                    location: {
                        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId3
                    },
                    stopover: true
                });
            }

            this.directionsService.route({
                origin: {
                    'placeId': this.originPlaceId
                },
                destination: {
                    'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId
                },
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: this.travelMode
            },
                function (response, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
                        // For each route, display summary information.
                        summaryPanel = ''
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
                            // alert(response.routes[0].legs[i].start_address)
                            // alert(response.routes[0].legs[i].end_address)
                            var routeSegment = i + 1;
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
                                '</b><br>';
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                        }
                        for (var j = 0; j < response.routes[0].waypoint_order.length; j++) {
                            var num = response.routes[0].waypoint_order[j];
                            alert(num)
                            // AllMarkers[i].setIcon("http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + (num + 1) +"|FF776B|000000")
                        }


                    } else {
                        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                    }
                });
        };

        function computeTotalDistance(result) {
            var total = 0;
            var myroute = result.routes[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;

            }
            total = total / 1000;
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
        }


    </script>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I actually want is when I drag the point I want to to update the address of that input box. I am stuck here because I have 2 waypoints, I dont understand from which I can update the stop address.
I want to update my changed marker address with that input text box

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. I don't think the 300+ lines of code you posted are the *minimal* code needed. Also please edit your question to include debugging details and write correct English for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

When the `direction_changed` event triggers on the `DirectionRenderer`, get the `start_address` for all the legs and put it in the appropriate `<input>`, put the `end_address` of the last leg, put that in the `<input id="end">`.

```
  this.directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    var routes = this.getDirections().routes[0];
    routes_list = []
    console.log(routes);
    for (var i = 0; i < routes.legs.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0)
        document.getElementById('start').value = routes.legs[i].start_address;
      if (i == 1)
        document.getElementById('waypoints1').value = routes.legs[i].start_address;
      if (i == 2) {
        document.getElementById('waypoints2').value = routes.legs[i].start_address;
        document.getElementById('end').value = routes.legs[i].end_address;
        }
    }
    computeTotalDistance(this.getDirections());
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4g8kpcne/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId2 = null;
  this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
  var originInput = document.getElementById('start');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('end');
  var destinationInput2 = document.getElementById('waypoints1');
  var destinationInput3 = document.getElementById('waypoints2');
  // var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  // var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
  var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  // added draggable marker option to the renderer and right panel
  this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });


  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
  originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete2 =
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput2);
  destinationAutocomplete2.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete3 =
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput3);
  destinationAutocomplete3.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete =
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);


  this.directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    var routes = this.getDirections().routes[0];
    routes_list = []
    console.log(routes);
    for (var i = 0; i < routes.legs.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0)
        document.getElementById('start').value = routes.legs[i].start_address;
      if (i == 1)
        document.getElementById('waypoints1').value = routes.legs[i].start_address;
      if (i == 2) {
        document.getElementById('waypoints2').value = routes.legs[i].start_address;
        document.getElementById('end').value = routes.legs[i].end_address;
      }
    }
    computeTotalDistance(this.getDirections());
  });
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete2, 'DEST2');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete3, 'DEST3');

  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput2);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput3);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
}

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;
  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    me.travelMode = mode;
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else if (mode === 'DEST') {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else if (mode === 'DEST2') {
      me.destinationPlaceId2 = place.place_id;
    } else if (mode === 'DEST3') {
      me.destinationPlaceId3 = place.place_id;
    }
    me.route();
  });

};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  console.log("originPlaceId=" + this.originPlaceId + " destinationPlaceId=" + this.destinationPlaceId + " destinationPlaceId2=" + this.destinationPlaceId2 + " destinationPlaceId3=" + this.destinationPlaceId3)
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }

  var me = this;

  var waypts = [];
  if (!!this.destinationPlaceId2) {
    waypts.push({
      location: {
        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId2
      },
      stopover: true
    });
  }

  if (!!this.destinationPlaceId3) {
    waypts.push({
      location: {
        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId3
      },
      stopover: true
    });
  }

  this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        'placeId': this.originPlaceId
      },
      destination: {
        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId
      },
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        // For each route, display summary information.
        summaryPanel = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
            '</b><br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < response.routes[0].waypoint_order.length; j++) {
          var num = response.routes[0].waypoint_order[j];
        }


      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
};

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;

  }
  total = total / 1000;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}
```

```css
/* Autocomplete styles */


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

#map {
  height: 70%;
  width: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#start,
#waypoints,
#end {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}

#start:focus,
#waypoints:focus,
#end:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#right-panel {
  float: right;
  width: 34%;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!--Autocomplete html -->
<input id="start" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter an origin location" value="The Bronx">

<input id="end" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a destination location" value="Edison, NJ">

<input id="waypoints1" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a stop" value="Newark, NJ">
<input id="waypoints2" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a stop" value="New York, NY">

<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
  <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
  <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
  <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Draggable directions hmtl -->
<div id="right-panel">
  <p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: i have tested it but on multiple drag it is changing the address of another field when i am moving the point A

Comment: in some cases it is working but i dont know sometime its not working

Comment: 1. What do you mean by: "can we make these stops or geocode dynamic"?  That sounds like a new question. 2. I don't see any issues when dragging point A multiple times, seems to always work for me (in the code snippet in the answer).  If you can reproduce the issue with the code snippet in my answer, please provide instructions.  If it is only in your codebase, then fixing that is another question.

Comment: when i enter the address in stop2 .address of stop2  is displaying on stop 1 and stop 1 address is displaying on stop 2. it is not working properly when i am dragging the stop.

Comment: i have tested it with so many times but it is not not proprly working this stops

Comment: And with start point A and end Point B on drag or move this is not changing the address it is changing the only start address not address of end location

Comment: waypoint or stops are optional without stops it is also not working you can test with start and end location. please test because it is not working

Comment: what actual i want is please use this below link :

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/28.5062228,77.0384/28.5285588,77.0706231/28.7102201,77.0809677/28.6548045,77.1869541/@28.6064357,76.9972859,11z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0

if you have any idea or any dummy code is there like same this please help me related this i will be very greatfull to you.

Comment: Looks like the placeIds and the associated text of the geocoded waypoints can change when the route is dragged, looks like it is just for places that have been previously dragged.  Saving the new placeIds after drag doesn't seem to help (and could be problematic if the user adds a waypoint using the drag functionality of the DirectionsRenderer).

Comment: [Test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4g8kpcne/1/) which demonstrates the issue (rewrote the code from the [example in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions), added the ability to add dynamic waypoints)